# Predicate without using ;

Tags: prolog

I have this two types of facts.

```
vowel(a).
vowel(e).

consonant(b).
consonant(c).
```

Now i need to implement a predicate letter/1. The most obvious way would be:

```
letter(X):-vowel(X); consonant(X).
```

But I need to define this predicate without using ; operator.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just define two separate rules for `letter(X)`:

```
letter(X) :- vowel(X).
letter(X) :- consonant(X).
```

If the first rule doesn't apply (i.e. `vowel(X)` is not true), then the second rule will be checked as well. In other words, if either `vowel(X)` or `consonant(X)` evaluate to true, then so will `letter(X)`. In effect, having multiple rules for a predicate acts as a logical or.

Comment: Oh so stupid of mine. So simples and totally forgot. Thank you

Comment: a small clarification: if the first rule does apply, the second will still be checked - just as with the `;` too. That's the nature of Prolog's disjunction: its possible solutions *are* all possible solutions from both its constituents.